# Needed: An efficient encoding scheme that bijects variable length, small alphabet strings to the natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What I have is an enumeration scheme which is binary in nature. The problem is that my strings are variable length. How do I choose an efficient encoding, where the codes "abc" and "00000000abc" are distinct, with a, b, c in { 0, 1 }, and in genere.

Sure, I could go to ternary, but I really feel this is suboptimal in my use case.

Also, by variable length I really mean potentially countably infinite sized strings. If I could prove a hard limit on the length of my strings, I would have a revolutionary result on my hands, so that's not going to happen, realistically.

I'd really appreciate any feedback here.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147747/discussion-on-question-by-emanuel-landeholm-needed-an-efficient-encoding-scheme); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple injective function from the set of finite $b$-ary strings to the set of natural numbers is to prepend a $1$ and interpret the resulting string as a $b$-ary number. For example, with $b=2$, the binary strings $ε,0,1,00,01,10,11,000$ are represented by the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ respectively.

This mapping is injective because we can remove the leading $1$ to recover the input string. When $k=2$, it's also surjective because every natural number starts with a $1$.